# How to save values of the GET method in an array and then accessing specific values

Tags: c#, arrays, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I need to access all the items that I have in my database and analyse each one of them. I was thinking I could save all the values into an array and then accessing them loke this:

```
     var ocorrenciasLista = GetOcorrencias().ToArray();     
     for (int i = 0; i <= ocorrenciasLista.Length; i++)
            {
                var latitude2 = ocorrenciasLista[i][2];
                
            }
```

**EDIT:**

Here is my GetOcorrencias()

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Ocorrencias> GetOcorrencias()
    {


        
        int duracao = 2;
        DateTime dataDuracao = DateTime.Now.Subtract(new TimeSpan(0, duracao, 0, 0));

        var ocorrencias = _context.Ocorrencias
                    .Where(e => (e.Estado == Ocorrencias.EstadoOcorrencia.emAvaliacao && e.DataOcorrencia >= dataDuracao) ||
                            e.Estado == Ocorrencias.EstadoOcorrencia.aceite);
            
        return ocorrencias;
    }
```

I get an error saying "Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type Ocorrencias". Ocorrencias is my main model.
In the code above I want to access the latitude of every item that is on my database. How should I do this?

Comment: What's the return type of `GetOcorrencias()`?

Comment: Also, retrieving ALL items in the database is almost always a bad idea. That defeats the purpose of having a database and querying it. You should query and retrieve only what you need, that's what querying languages (such as SQL) are there for.

Comment: The GetOcorrencias returns an IEnumerable, and on that mehtod I'm only returning what I'll need

Comment: OK, so you get an `IEnumerable`, but you're using it as a jagged array here: `ocorrenciasLista[i][2]`. If you want to access it as a jagged array, then return an array from the method.

Comment: @TeresaAlves The `GetOcorrencias().ToArray()` just returns an `Ocorrencias[]`, which, wen indexed into with `ocorrenciasLista[i]` returns an `Ocorrencias` instance. Now `Ocorrencias` needs to implement an indexer for your `[2]` to work. Can you show a bit more code?

Comment: But if I want to keep it an IEnumerable how will I access it?

Comment: @sunside I added some more code. I just need to access a specific element of every item I have on my database

Comment: Looking at your added info, that method simply return an `IEnumerable<Ocorrencias>`, so it doesn't make any sense you're trying to access it as a jagged array in your calling function. You can simply do `var latitude2 = ocorrenciasLista[i];` in your loop and refer to each object instance in the `IEnumerable`.

Comment: That's it. It worked just fine, thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you want your method to return an `IEnumerable` you have to do something like this:

Say this is your class:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And change the return type of your `GetOcorrencias()` to the following. I have a sample method here:

```
static IEnumerable<SomeClass[]> GetOcorrencias()
{
    var data = new SomeClass[2][];
    data[0] = new SomeClass[1] { new SomeClass() { Name = "A" } };
    data[1] = new SomeClass[1] { new SomeClass() { Name = "B" } };
    return data;
}
```

Now you can access it like a jagged array in your main:

```
var data = GetOcorrencias().ToArray();

for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
{
    var datai = data[i][0];
}
```